# How to display HTMLpropertiescollection (toString/object property)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm writing a remote/in-browser logging tool (basically an in browser console so I can remote debug mobile devices and whatnot) and I am having trouble printing/accessing some raw DOM elements and objects (They appear to be objects when I log them to the console). When call `bronsole` (don't judge me) on the event object some of the DOM objects are not being looped through as if the for loop doesn't recognise it as an object. One of the objects in question is the `HTMLpropertiescollection`. I don't have any particular need for this oject specifically but I am logging touch events and it would be nice to be able to read all of the properties of the event object.

```
(function ($) {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth" style="position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); z-index: 1000000; overflow-y: auto; padding-top: 40px;"><div id="seouihtoeuitnei98e797etuiST" style="position:absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; background-color: #C0504D; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></div></div>');
    $('#eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth').click(function(e){
        if($(this).height() <= 150){
            $(this).animate({height: '100%'});
        }else{
            $(this).animate({height: '150px'});
        }
    });
    $('#seouihtoeuitnei98e797etuiST').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if($(this).parent().height() <= 30){
            $(this).parent().animate({height: '100%'});
        }else{
            $(this).parent().animate({height: '0px'});
        }
    });
    $('#eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth').on('click','.oseu098oaeuno7e089',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if($(this).height() > 15){
            $(this).css('height', '15px');
            $.each($(this).children('.oseu098oaeuno7e089'), function(){
            $(this).css('height', '15px');
            });
        }else{
            $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        }
        if($('#eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth').height() <= 100){
            $('#eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth').animate({height: '100%'});
        }
    });
    $('#eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth').on('click','.oeusn0eui0HTDRh98oeui',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    window.uonteuho8o6e8ued68uou8Color = ['#6BC3FF','#FF494F','#00D3D3','#77FF6B','#DBD300','#D470FF'];
    var entityMap = {
        "&": "&amp;",
        "<": "&lt;",
        ">": "&gt;",
        '"': '&quot;',
        "'": '&#39;',
        "/": '&#x2F;'
    };
    function escapeHtml(string) {
        return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
            return entityMap[s];
        });
    }
    function htmlConsole(param){
        var obj = (typeof param.NTDNTH8oe8uidu98NT != 'undefined') ? param.NTDNTH8oe8uidu98NT : param;
        var index = (typeof param.sjtnhxsSTHxsnheu9isTH != 'undefined') ? param.sjtnhxsSTHxsnheu9isTH : null;
        var preKey = (typeof param.sntuhinegdukx0euetkhe989 != 'undefined') ? '[' + param.sntuhinegdukx0euetkhe989 + ']: ' : '';
        var spaceAdd = (typeof param.sNDGHBn788rnFI9 != 'undefined') ? param.sNDGHBn788rnFI9 + '____' : '';
        var depth = (typeof param.netnuxie0xbenuihtdNT09 != 'undefined') ? param.netnuxie0xbenuihtdNT09 + 1 : '0';
        var element = '';
        if(typeof obj != null){
            if(typeof obj == 'string' || typeof obj == 'number' || typeof obj == 'boolean'){
                element += ('<p class="oeusn0eui0HTDRh98oeui" style="color: white; padding:2px;margin:2px; background-color: orange;"><span style="visibility:hidden">' + spaceAdd + '</span>' + preKey + escapeHtml(String(obj)) + '</p>');
            }else{
                var end = ('<p style="color: white; padding:2px;margin:2px;"><span style="visibility:hidden">' + spaceAdd + '</span>' + ')</p></div>');
                element += ('<div id="oestniSTHSseti897e_' + depth + '" class="oseu098oaeuno7e089" style="color: white; padding:2px;margin:2px; height: 15px; overflow:hidden; cursor: pointer; background-color: ' + window.uonteuho8o6e8ued68uou8Color[depth%6] + '"><span style="visibility:hidden">' + spaceAdd + '</span>' + preKey + Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ) + '(<br>');
                if(Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ) == '[object Function]'){
                    element += ('<p class="oeusn0eui0HTDRh98oeui" style="color: white; padding:2px;margin:2px; background-color: orange;"><span style="visibility:hidden">' + spaceAdd + '___' + '</span>' + escapeHtml(String(obj)) + '</p>');
                }

                if(depth < 10){ // this is because I fudge up the script with "too much recursion" on big objects. I'm in the middle of solving this, hence the redundant properties
                    for(var key in obj){
                        element += htmlConsole({NTDNTH8oe8uidu98NT: obj[key], sNDGHBn788rnFI9: spaceAdd, sntuhinegdukx0euetkhe989: key,netnuxie0xbenuihtdNT09: depth,sjtnhxsSTHxsnheu9isTH: index}).element;
                    }
                }else{
                    element += end;
                    return {element: element, obj:obj};
                }
                element += end;
            }
        }   
        return {element: element};
    }
    $.bronsole = function(obj){
        $('#eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth').prepend(htmlConsole(obj).element);
    };
    $.fn.bronsole = function(text){
        var _this = this;
        if(typeof text != 'undefined'){
            $('#eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth').prepend(htmlConsole(text).element);
        }
        $('#eoenuitn345n34ntdhiu45dnth').prepend(htmlConsole(_this).element);
        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: `HTMLPropertiesCollection` is a collection of parent elements whose children are special HTML5 `microdata` elements, which are a relatively new thing. So I would figure the page you are testing this on has no `microdata`, so `HTMLPropertiesCollection` would be empty:

http://www.html-5.com/javascript/html-properties-collection-interface/

http://www.html-5.com/microdata/index.html#microdata-properties

Comment: I can `console.log(HTMLPropertiesCollection)` and I get something like 
`getlength
 0
 
getnames
 Object { length=0, item=item(), contains=contains()}
 
@@iterator
 @@iterator()
 
item
 item()
 
namedItem
 namedItem()
 
__proto__`

Comment: Werid. I guess I need more context, I just get `HTMLPropertiesCollection()` when I log it, and `undefined` when i `for (k in HTMLPropertiesCollection) {console.log(k);}`

Comment: A peculiar thing indeed. What browser are you using?

Comment: Im using FF 29. Couldn't even get that far in Chrome 37, just got the old "ReferenceError: HTMLPropertiesCollection is not defined" when I tried to do anything with it.

Comment: I just realized how misleading my comment was. When I put `console.log(HTMLPropertiesCollection)` I meant to show that that was in the conditional 
`if(Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ) == '[object HTMLPropertiesCollection]'){
                    console.log(obj);
                }` I deleted that snippet before asking the question

Comment: Ah. I think this happens in a specific enough context that you should create a fiddle so the same circumstances can be replicated